# Order colnames of top n values for each site and generate results in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a sites (rows) - species (columns) data frame which includes abundances of species. I try to generate a data frame including top n species for each site in R. My current data includes 353 species and 99 sites including percent cover data. I will apply the solution for my data but it would be great if the solution could be applied for any similar data, which includes hundreds of species and sites.

Here is my data how it looks like.

```
      sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8 sp9 sp10
site1  0   6   1   25  0   0   2   3  40   15 
site2  0   1   2   1   0   60  0   0   0   30
site3  15  7   0   10  0   0   55  0   0   0.5
site4  1   1   4   0   2   0   0   80  0   0
site5  0   0   58  0   1   1   2   1   3   0
```

I would like to generate a data frame which includes top n species for each site (here for top 3 species)

```
site1  sp9  sp4  sp10
site1   40   25   15
site2  sp6  sp10 sp3
site2   60   30    2
site3  sp7  sp1  sp4
site3   55   15   10
site4  sp8  sp3  sp5
site4   80   4    2
site5  sp3  sp9  sp7
site5   58   3    2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can first set the rownames as site and then reshape the data to long. The key here is to arrange the values and then extract the top three in this case I have used `row_number()`. After that you can combine the values separated by `,` and create a variable so that they can be reshaped to wide. Once this is done, you can use `separate_rows()` to reach the expected structure. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% rownames_to_column('site') %>%
  pivot_longer(-site) %>%
  arrange(site,desc(value)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(row_number()<=3) %>%
  mutate(Var=paste0('V',row_number()),
         value=as.character(value),
         content=paste0(name,',',value)) %>% select(-c(name,value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=content) %>%
  separate_rows(c(V1,V2,V3),sep=',')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   site [5]
   site  V1    V2    V3   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 site1 sp9   sp4   sp10 
 2 site1 40    25    15   
 3 site2 sp6   sp10  sp3  
 4 site2 60    30    2    
 5 site3 sp7   sp1   sp4  
 6 site3 55    15    10   
 7 site4 sp8   sp3   sp5  
 8 site4 80    4     2    
 9 site5 sp3   sp9   sp7  
10 site5 58    3     2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(sp1 = c(0L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 0L), sp2 = c(6L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 0L), sp3 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 58L), sp4 = c(25L, 1L, 10L, 
0L, 0L), sp5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), sp6 = c(0L, 60L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), sp7 = c(2L, 0L, 55L, 0L, 2L), sp8 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 80L, 1L
), sp9 = c(40L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L), sp10 = c(15, 30, 0.5, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("site1", 
"site2", "site3", "site4", "site5"))
```

Also keep in mind that the output is of nature character in its variables.